# What does "Like a jug that's googling out buttermilk" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Reading "Adventures of Huckleberry Finn" on Project Gutenberg I come across a sentence I can't quite comprehend. Also, word "googling" caught my eye:

> whilst he made all sorts of signs with his hands and said "Goo-goo—goo-goo-goo" all the time, like a baby that can't talk
>   ...
>   The duke he never let on he suspicioned what was up, but just went a goo-gooing around, happy and satisfied, like a jug that's googling out buttermilk.

I would thought it's an OCR error, and something like "gurgling" meant instead, but there is a scanned page adjacent to the text, with the same word in print: http://www.gutenberg.org/files/76/76-h/76-h.htm

So, I am eager to know the meaning of the word "googling" in this context([this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/45883/51339) weren't of much help). Also, it would be nice to get the meaning of the whole idiom "like a jug that's googling out buttermilk".

Comment: It is a variant spelling of gurgling - and a jug with the thick butter milk will go GLUG, GLUG, GLUG where each GLUG is an amount of milk - I added the text where they describe what he is doing

Comment: Thanks, that's good hint. But what about "happy and satisfied" part? I thought this buttermilk idiom is about such a mood - no?

Comment: Not that I can see. Just going goo goo as a baby is the mood he is in

Comment: Yup, I see now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like an example of [onomatopoeia](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onomatopoeia) to me...that's the sound of (thick) buttermilk coming out of the jug.

(Unless of course it's a highly intelligent form of jug that is capable of time travel, using a web browser.)

Answer (score 2):

SUPPLEMENTARY to JeffSahol's answer:

*Goo-goo*, *gurgle* and *google* here are all onomatopoeic terms invented to imitate a natural sound.

*Goo-goo* is traditionally associated with the happy sounds made by babies, and that is probably what Huck means by *goo-gooing around*. *Gurgle*, according to the OED, is paralleled by similar words in other languages, and it is “not clear” whether the English word is borrowed or independently developed; words in Romance languages may have some relationship to the Latin *gurgulio*, gullet or windpipe.

*OED* does not give a comparable meaning here for *google*, which it regards as a variant of *goggle*; that in turn has two broad senses, as a variant of *gobble* and to stare with protuberant eyes.  I would therefore think that the use here is Huck's own onomatopoeic coinage, with a reference back to the earlier baby sounds.